# Mostrar datos de formulario en otra vista

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo que pasar los datos de un formulario, mediante un controlador a una vista nueva (diferente a la del formulario).

He escrito lo siguiente:

En web.php:

```
//ruta para meter datos y llamar al controlador:
Route::get('/formalumno','AlumnosController@mostrar');

//ruta para mostrar datos en una vista nueva:
Route::post('/veralumno/{nombre}/{nota}','AlumnosController@mostrar');
```

En AlumnosController.php:

```
$nombre=$_POST['nombre']:
$nota=$_POST['nota']:
public function mostrar($nombre,$nota){
    $cal="No apto";
    if($nota>=5){
        $cal="Apto";
    }
    return view('veralumno',['nombre'=>$nombre,'cal'=>$cal]);
}
```

En el formulario formalumno.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Formulario Alumno</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name='formulario_alumno' action='formalumno' method='post'>
    <div>
       <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?php $nombre ?>"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="nota">Nota:</label>
        <input type="number" name="nota" value="<?php $nota ?>"/>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="ENVIAR"><br>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Y en veralumno.php:

```
<?php
    echo $nombre." ".$cal;
?>
```

Me da un error en el controlador:

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$nombre' (T_VARIABLE),
>   expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que tienes un lio de conceptos, pongamos un poco de orden.

Declaramos primero las rutas

```
// Ruta para mostrar el formulario, método get
Route::get('/formalumno', 'AlumnosController@crear');
// Ruta para recibir datos del formulario y mostrarlos, método post
Route::post('/veralumno','AlumnosController@mostrar');
```

Fijate que en la ruta `/veralumno` no espero datos sobre la ruta (por get) (`{nombre}/{nota}`) estos serán enviados por el formulario con post. Y en la ruta `/formalumno` llamo al método crear (`AlumnosController@crear`).

Supongamos que tenemos 2 archivos para las vistas de alumnos en la ruta `resources/views/alumno/`, llamadas `crear.blade.php` y `mostrar.blade.php`. La primera con el formulario y la segunda que mostrará los datos enviados desde la primera.

Ahora en el controlador debemos definir 2 métodos crear y mostrar.

`crear()` que llamará a la vista `crear.blade.php`  y `mostrar()` que recibirá los datos del formulario y llamara a la vista `mostrar.blade.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
// Incluimos la clase Request 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AlumnosController extends Controller
{
    // Creamos un método para mostrar el form
    public function crear()
    {
        // retornamos la vista del formulario 
    return view('alumno.crear');
    }

    // Creamos un método para recibir los datos del form
    public function mostrar(Request $request)
    {
        // retornamos la vista mostrar y le pasamos los datos que necesitemos  
    return view('alumno.mostrar')
                     ->with('nombre', $request->nombre)
                     ->with('nota', $request->nota);
                    // with() nos permite pasar variables a la vista
                    // el primer parámetros es el nombre con el que estará disponible en la vista
                    // el segundo son los datos. 
    }
}
```

<sub>Nota: la definición de las vistas quedaría tal cual las tienes, solo tendrías que ubicarlas en la ruta `resources/views/alumno/` y renombrarlas con los nombres indicados más arriba. También debes añadir el **token csrf** al formulario, más info [aquí(documentación)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf) y [aquí(¿Qué es?)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/102233/qu%C3%A9-es-exactamente-el-token-csrf-field-que-se-le-a%C3%B1ade-a-los-formulario-en-lara/102282)</sub>

El uso de `$_POST` o `$_GET` en Laravel es totalmente innecesario, laravel provee una clase (`Request`) para manejar esto de una forma más adecuada puedes revisar la documentación al respecto aqui: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests

Comment: Para utilizar el método post en laravel debes añadir el token crsf, creo que es lo que te falta, https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf

Comment: Después de hacer todo lo anterior, me mostraba bien el formulario, pero al darle al botón ENVIAR, me aparece esto en letras grandes: "The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again." Busqué por internet y encontré que hay que poner en el formulario esto: {{ csrf_field() }} No se para que sirve, pero me funcionó el ejercicio. Gracias a los dos.

Comment: @CharlyUtrilla Puedes revisar esta pregunta para hacerte una idea para que sirve el token csrf: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/102233/qu%C3%A9-es-exactamente-el-token-csrf-field-que-se-le-a%C3%B1ade-a-los-formulario-en-lara/102282 . Añadí igualmente los enlaces a la respuesta. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

En ambas rutas estás llamado al mismo método `@mostrar`. En la ruta GET `formalumno` debes retornar la vista hacia tu formulario. Si ya has definido en tu ruta POST indicar el {nombre} y la {nota}, no hay necesidad que uses $_POST para esas variables. Por ejemplo, si esta es la ruta users/edit/{id} para cargar el formulario de edición de un usuario, que llama al método edit. El método edit también recibe el id. Se podría definir el método edit de esta manera:

```
function edit($id) {
$myID = $id;
...
}
```

Con respecto a la la línea `return view('veralumno',['nombre'=>$nombre,'cal'=>$cal]);` hay una función que puedes utilizar para enviar datos a tu vista, y que no sea tan engorroso como definir un Array, la función se llama compact y puedes enviar tantas variables como desees. En tu caso, con la variable compact el resultado sería algo como:

```
return view('veralumno', compact('nombre', 'cal'))
```