# error de rutas laravel

Tags: php, laravel

tengo la siguiente ruta

```
Route::post('guardar_registro', 'Frontoffice\Perfil_paciente\completar_registroController@guardar_registro');
```

y el siguiente form

```
<form action="{{ url('guardar_registro') }}"  method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8" autocomplete="off" >
```

pero no encuentra la ruta al mandar el submit

Comment: Por qué la ruta q tu controller es así?

Comment: No debería partir solo de completarRegistroController?

Comment: xq despues del @espesifico el metodo ya tengo otros asi y funciona pero ese no . aunq los otros no uso form uso metodo ajax

Comment: ¿Aparece la ruta en el listado de rutas de Artisan?

Comment: Bienvenido Jon Solis a StackOverflow español, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y asi obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Adicionalmente revisa [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. 
¿Podrías indicar si te aparece algún error al hacer el submit?

Comment: Y si solo añades ` \ ` en la ruta: url('\guardar_registro')

Comment: Por casualidad, estas enviando el [token crsf](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/102233/qu%c3%a9-es-exactamente-el-token-csrf-field-que-se-le-a%c3%b1ade-a-los-formulario-en-lara/102282?r=SearchResults#102282) ? Que error exacto es el que obtienes?

Comment: Te recomiendo usar el metodo ```name``` para nombrar tus rutas y luego usar metodo ```route``` para llamarlas, ve este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50487047/url-vs-route-in-laravel-5-6) porque al parecer resuelve tu mismo problema.

Answer (score 0):

Yo prefiero declarar las rutas de esta manera:

```
Route::post('conceptos-de-pagos/guardar', [
    'as' => 'conceptos-pagos.store', // agrego un alias a la ruta para acceder a las vistas
    'uses' => 'ConceptosPagosController@store'  // hago referencia a la acción "store" del controlador
    ]);
```

Para ocuparlas así:

```
{{ route("conceptos-pagos.store}}' // utilizo el alias de la ruta en las vistas
```