# Mostrar vista de laravel en android con usuario autentificado

Tags: android, laravel, flutter

Saludos y mi duda es la siguiente, Tengo una aplicación en Android que se autentifica con laravel que me regresa un token y quiero mostrar una vista mediante un metodo http get. Al recibir la pagina para mostrar en Android me muestra la pantalla de inicio y creo es por que solo hago la petición get. ¿Que necesito hacer para que se muestre la vista? o ¿donde tengo que mandar el token para que al solicitar la vista por el http get este no me regrese a la pantalla de inicio?

Aqui la pantalla de bienvenida en el sitio Web
[image: Entrada al sitio web en laravel]

mi código donde me autentifico y guardo el token

[image: Android autentificacion mediante API REST]

realizo la consulta de la vista

[image: Consulta de la vista]

Y la respuesta de laravel es la pagina de inicio. Estoy seguro que es por que laravel no me reconoce como usuario autentificado y no he encontrado si tengo que mandar el tiekn en el header o de que manera me puede responder con la vista solicitada. En Laravel me muestra correctamente la vista pero en android es mi problema.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Hasta donde sé, la mejor forma de que dos o más aplicaciones interactúen con una misma información es haciendo una api/servicio web. Si tuvieras el código a la mano y lo agregaras sería más sencillo que te ayuden.

Comment: Gracias ya complete la pregunta y espero alguien pueda ayudar.

Comment: estas mandando los valores correctos en el post? puedes ver si en el server recibes esos valores?

Comment: Diego no estoy mandando nada en el post ya que desconozco que debo de mandar y si en realidad es un post y no un get.

Answer (score 0):

Creo haber encontrado la respuesta y de ante mano agradezco la atención de quienes aportaron con sus comentarios a solucionar mi problema. Me parece que la respuesta esta en CSRF Protection de laravel donde me pide ingresar el siguiente encabezado

`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"`

Si alguien tiene alguna información adicional la agradecería mucho.

Saludos.

Comment: desde Laravel 5.6 la sintaxis es `@csrf` si necesitas comprender para que sirve, tienes 2 opciones: 1.- [La documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf), 2.- [Respuesta dada en esta comunidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/102233/qu%C3%A9-es-exactamente-el-token-csrf-field-que-se-le-a%C3%B1ade-a-los-formulario-en-lara)